# PHAsset get photo location title

Tags: ios8

on iOS8 when using the Photos app you are able to see the location title when viewing each specific photo. For example "Home" or "Central Park" - how do I get that data/string from the PHAsset or similar class?

I don't see a localizedTitle or similar property on the PHAsset class.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should get asset coordinates from appropriate property from PHAsset. Then by means of CLGeocoder get information about place. Example...

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:asset.location
               completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                   CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks firstObject];
                   NSLog(@"%@", placemark.name);
               }];
```

Don't forget import CoreLocation Framework.

Answer (score -1):

PHAsset has a property called creationDate, you  can get the date using someAsset.creationDate

Comment: He's asking for a title, not a date :)